# How to modify the std::valarray class from STL?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I have valarray of bool valarrays and I need to sort them with my custom function of elements comparison.
I.e. if a length of each element is 4 then I wish them to be sorted as following:

```
0000, 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, 0011, 0101, 1001, 0110, 1010, ...
```

Here is my function:

```
inline bool operator<(const std::valarray<bool>& lhs, const std::valarray<bool>& rhs) {
    if (lhs.soze() != rhs.size()) return 0;
    if (lhs.sum() < rhs.sum()) return 1;
    if (lhs.sum() > rhs.sum()) return 0;
    for (int i = lhs.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (lhs[i] < rhs[i]) return 0;
        if (lhs[i] > rhs[i]) return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a new class having the same functionality but modified comparison operators.
If I use decorator, I would have to specify decorated classname wheninitializing my object:

```
MyValarray* mv = new MyValarray(new std::valarray<bool>(4));
```

If I use inheritance I would have to define all valarray constructors.
I want it to be a stand-alone class. How to do it in the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you out. C++11 introduced this new syntax for inheriting constructors:

```
class MyClass : public std::valarray<bool> {
    public:
        using std::valarray<bool>::valarray;

        // ...
};
```

You may use this to make up your second approach by inheriting from `std::valarray<bool>` without writing the constructors.

Comment: @user162065: If you don't want to make a *whole* new class, repeating all the constructors, and potentially mistyping something, then yes, its an excellent practice. It got into the standard by some reason, no? ;).

Comment: But it wasn't in standard by some reason. When should I use decorator instead of inheritance?

Comment: I couldn't find any example of decorating object from the standard library.

Comment: @user162065: Ehm... Sorry, but what do you mean by "decorator"? There's no such concept in C++, IIRC...

Comment: @user162065: Well, I would have understood if you said "wrapper", but anyway. What kind of wrapper are you expecting? First of all, why do you want a wrapper? The purpose of my answer is to *avoid* the need for a wrapper. A `MyClass` is a `std::valarray<bool>`, and can be initialized in exactly the same ways. The only difference is that you may overload whatever you feel appropiate to.